# Unity 2D C# - Collider not working

Tags: c#, collision-detection, collision, unity-game-engine

I am working on a ***2D* TopDown** game in ***Unity 5***. The collision is not working at all.
The player and the obstacle both have a ***2D* Collider** and they are not Trigger. The player has a ***2D* Rigidbody** with *Kinematic* set to *false*, *gravity scale* is equal to *zero*. Maybe the movement code has something to do with it.
The code is a bit long so I'll just show you the code for moving up:

```
if (Input.GetAxis ("Up") > 0) {

    if (movingDown == false) {

        posY += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        movingUp = true;
    }
} else {

    movingUp = false;
}
```

/.../

```
transform.position = new Vector3 (posX, posY, 0);
```

It is always setting the value of the position as long as you are pressing the up button. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Anyway to solve this you need to check your Physics Settings in Edit > Project Settings > Physics. Min Penetration For Penalty or Solver Iteration Count can correct your problem. I know that you are using "isKinematic = false". However, (for future references) if you have two isKinematic elements the collision detection won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are setting the position directly. So at each frame, you are telling unity exactly were the object should be, which overrides the position that would be computed from collision.

To fix this, you need to modify your movement code to add a force to your rigidbody and leave the position untouched ( see rigidbody doc, and function AddForce (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html)

Comment: I tried adding AddForce but the player would go faster and faster and it would look like his walking on ice. So I tried with the velocity variable like this rb.velocity = new Vector3(x, y, 0); So thanks for shouting that out to me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
    rb.velocity = new Vector3 (rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y, ConstantZValue);
```

This replaces your system with a velocity-based system as updating the `transform.postition` of a rigidbody is not recommended. With the system you have, the collision is not being detected because the `rigidbody` isn't being updated.